# Node.js subdomains

Tags: node.js, express, subdomain

I'm trying to get my Node.js powered site to run on one instance serving multiple domains. I have my main domain, `example.com` and then I have `admin.example.com` and `api.example.com` which all have different routes etc, *I'm using Express.*

So far I've added two A records for the subdomains, and also added two entries into `/var/vhosts` on my CentOS box.

```
127.0.0.1 api.example.com
127.0.0.1 admin.example.com
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

I'm aware that Express has a `express.vhost` method so I've already tried:

```
app.use(express.vhost('api.example.com', require('./lib/subdomains/api')))
app.use(express.vhost('admin.example.com', require('./lib/subdomains/admin')))
```

But that still only serves my main routes which is imported below. What am I missing?

Comment: What's in, say, `./lib/subdomains/api`?

Comment: Something along the lines of [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/jbrooksuk/5300772) the thing I was trying was to do at one point was `app.use(express.vhost('api.example.com', require('./lib/subdomains/api').app))`

Comment: Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/5300792) that works just fine for me. Are you checking in a browser or with a CLI tool? If the latter, is it sending the correct `Host` header?

Comment: In the browser. Your code is the same as what I have, except for that I have beneath my `app.configure` this `require('./lib/routes')(app);` Is it possible that the `app` is clashing?

Comment: Could `/var/vhosts` be an Apache-thing? I just realised that usually, to create new host entries, you edit `/etc/hosts`. The `app`'s shouldn't be clashing, Node has a module scope so `app` in one module is separate from `app` in another module.

Comment: Yeah it is, Apache isn't installed mind, but httpd is. Thing is, I'm not sure if this is required.

Comment: Well if you don't get any errors trying to open `api.example.com` your browser can resolve it just fine, so it's probably not the reason for your problem :)

Comment: I have done, but it resolves to the main site routes.

Comment: Could you post your routing/middleware setup? Including `app.configure` and stuff. Perhaps there's something going on there.

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/jbrooksuk/5300966) should be everything you need.

Comment: The only way I see this failing is if you declare any routes *before* your `app.configure`. Otherwise, it looks fine (and works okay for me).

Comment: Bizarre. Does it work for you if you include the `api` routes in a separate file? Here is a cut down version of my `app.js`. https://gist.github.com/jbrooksuk/5301027

Comment: I've got it working! I had `req` and `res` params the wrong way round in my `api.js` module and it was causing crashes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If anybody else finds this question, you might want to check that you're passing your vhost route parameters the right way around.

I was using:

```
app.get('/', function(res, req) { /* Do stuff.. */ }
```

When it should be. The first argument for the callback function is `req`, then the second one is `res`.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) { /* Do stuff.. */ }
```

Be diligent with your code :)